# SwiftUI Firebase - Assigning default value to a Firebase Timestamp data type

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, codable

I am having trouble assigning a default value to a Firebase Timestamp data type

This is my model:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct MiniSite: Codable, Identifiable {
       
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name:String
    var city: String
    var country: String
    var region: String? = ""
    @ServerTimestamp var createDate: Timestamp?   
   
}
```

My Firebase data is like this:

```
name:"Clerigos Tower"
city :"Porto",
country:"Portrugal",
createDate: "March 3, 2021 at 4:19:53 PM UTC+2"(timestamp)
```

My code for reading the Firebase data is from Peter Friese's video "Build a To-Do List App with SwiftUI and Firebase"

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class MSiteRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    
    @Published var sites = [MiniSite] ()
    func loadData() {
        db.collection("sites")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                    self.sites = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                        do {
                            let x = try  document.data(as: MiniSite.self)
                            return x
                        }
                        catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If my record contains a createDate, then everything works fine. But createDate is optional in my database and so I have defined it in my model accordingly
`@ServerTimestamp var createDate: Timestamp?`

If the document in Firebase does not contain a createDate field I get the following error during the decode:

`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "createDate", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"createDate\", intValue: nil) (\"createDate\").", underlyingError: nil))`

It's okay that createDate be nil for those records that don't have a createDate field. The problem is that these records are not being added to my sites array.

I've tried the following:

1. Adding a default value for the createDate

`@ServerTimestamp var createDate: Timestamp?=nil`

2. Adding a CodingKeys enum

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct MiniSite: Codable, Identifiable {
       
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name:String
    var city: String
    var country: String
    var region: String? = ""
    @ServerTimestamp var createDate: Timestamp?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case city
        case country
        case createDate
    }
    
}
```

Neither of these had any effect on the results

I don't need to update the database so I also tried to remove the @ServerTimestamp from the createDate field. That also didn't help

Comment: Did you try removing `@ServerTimestamp` *and* making it an optional (`Timestamp?`)?

Comment: No I hadn't tried that, and that solves the problem. Thanks @jnpdx for you help!

Answer (score 0):

As provided by @jnpdx in the comments the solution is to remove the @ServerTimestamp annotation and use an optional Timestamp.

Change

```
    @ServerTimestamp var createDate: Timestamp?
```

to

```
    var createDate: Timestamp?
```